# Location service disabled message default not showing in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app the CLLocationManager is used to get the current user location. If the GPS is disabled by the user, then I'm expecting the default alert from apple asking to turn on the GPS services and giving an option to navigate to the settings page.

I'm not getting this alert even for the for the first time I launch the app.

Comment: So your question is? How to turn on the alert box? or Why it does not showing the alert box?

Comment: My question is why the alert is not showing every time i start the app. I think its showing only after a time out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the default GPS unavailable alert is shown then it will be showed for that app only after a certain period of time. I'm not sure about that time interval.